# Generic Type in an array throws "Cannot find name 'T' "

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
interface Process<T> {
  first: () => T[];
  second: (d: T) => void;

}

const PROCESSES: Process<T>[] = [
  {
    first: () => [{car: "car1"}],
    second: (car: {car: string}) => {},

  },
  {
    first: () => [{person: "person1"}],
    second: (person: {car: string}) => {}, // => How to make TS mark this as an error because is not a persona type?
  },
];
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPZIM7YDwAqAfMgN4BQyyMwU2YAXMgBQCUyAvCQQNoC6AbkrJsEBBhAATJs2nIC7LsgBuGYJKHkAvuXLiQ9NACUA8gGEAogGUr1puiwRchIv07IewilSo06jFkUSHlIEOCgmACIwqABGSK0%20ABphKlF9OWYYplDwpnooUABzLSCyLRThCq9U6lp6GTKQgAdobAko1roJeMSUnxExCUyu9pAc7JEwQpASstIK5AB6Jc4SAAkMAHdkMAxkAFs4AGsUAitD8OPdgAtgbGQ4B7gQZGhMKGQAIzE4AFdRMh7sgQBgwI9kKMJHBdgBPVoAfiqKUEQA)

The problem is that TypeScript throws this error: `Cannot find name 'T'.`

Comment: You use the generic name `T` when you define the interface or type. You cannot use it to declare types of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the generic name `T` when you define the interface or type. You cannot use it to declare types of variables. You need to create a type/interface for `Car` and `Person` and use them in the declaration of `PROCESSES` instead of `T`.

```js
interface Process<T> {
  first: () => T[];
  second: (d: T) => void;
}

type Car = { car: string };
type Person = { person: string };

const PROCESSES: (Process<Car> | Process<Person>)[] = [
  {
    first: () => [{ car: 'car1' }],
    second: (car: Car) => {}, // => works
  },
  {
    first: () => [{ person: 'person1' }],
    second: (person: Person) => {}, // => works
  },
  {
    first: () => [{ person: 'person1' }],
    second: (person: Car) => {}, // => Error!
];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to manually specify all the types of the elements in the `processes` array, you can use a factory function like this:

```js
function createProcesses<
  T extends any[] | [any]
  >(process: { [I in keyof T]: { first: () => T[I][], second: (d: T[I]) => void } }){
  return process
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPZIM7YDwAqAfMgN4CwAUMsjMFNmAFzIAUAlMgLwkEDaAXQDcVGtggIMIACYtWs5AU49kANwzBpIygF8qVMAE8ADigDCcKNzLIElloyigA5sh3ajptNGxTrpZFMGKQcwJxBXd31KSRBGQMwccWxrBCgIOEh0LAhcXNY+UTIimjoGZjZlEj4AuygWAHI6gEYGtwEAGhLkcViFVjqqsh0O5AB6Me4SAHcMKABrbCKRoopqGlp6RjkhmsCfEOQGoN8QVvau9bEJKX6TqSHSEfHJlVmFpfWV9bWNzfKdlNkHt7iBGqDzjpOt1erc5KCWBYoI9nhMgQBRKCYKAAQmWVAE7GiMAAriAEGBgH40hksolcsk8EUCMgIAAPSAyFJwECGQTIAA+wJ5hgERSIrGM9NwLACfAAkshQMh5hBDBgYIoBLL-ttKkD+PKBIJRrCZHIFIbCUD1Jo3G52L9kOkwCSoCAEjlcFQdEA)

```
const processes = createProcesses([
  {
    first: () => [{ car: 'car1' }],
    second: (car) => {}, // => works, car inferred as Car
  },
  {
    first: () => [{ person: 'person1' }],
    second: (person) => {}, // => works, person inferred as Person
  },
  {
    first: () => [{ person: 'person1' }],
    second: (person: Car) => {}, // => Error!
  }
])
```